# air customize about window

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder, mxml

I work with Flashbuilder 4.6 and Air application on Mas Os and I'd like to customize "About MyApp" window.

I know that all information about this window is in Adobe AIR Application Descriptor File, but I don't know how to customize.

Do you know how to do that?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's still relevant, but I'd say create a new window without system chrome:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e09.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a452d-7ff4

Then you just have to make everything inside the windows yourself, just how you like it.

What is it actually that you want to customize?